# Error when creating Web Service Client Test on Eclipse Luna

Tags: web-services, wsdl, eclipse-luna

I've created a Dynamic Web Project and tried to add a Web Client from a WSDL.

I'm using Eclipse Luna for Java EE and JDK 1.7.

On the final screen for adding a Web Service Client, when I click on Finish I get the following warning messages:

```
IWAB0182W The Sample JSP client does not support the following type: {0} org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.cloudmovil.v1_0.NamedParameter[]

IWAB0237W The Sample JSP client does not support arrays: {0}operatorUser

IWAB0189W The Sample JSP client omitted some methods because they contained unsupported types.
```

And finally I get an error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.sampleapp.codegen.InputFileAttributeGenerator.visit(InputFileAttributeGenerator.java:57)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.codegen.RelVisitor.run(RelVisitor.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.sampleapp.codegen.InputFileTypeGenerator.visit(InputFileTypeGenerator.java:294)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.codegen.RelVisitor.run(RelVisitor.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.sampleapp.codegen.InputFileHelp2Generator.visit(InputFileHelp2Generator.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.codegen.RelVisitor.run(RelVisitor.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.sampleapp.codegen.InputFileHelp1Generator.visit(InputFileHelp1Generator.java:78)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.codegen.RelVisitor.run(RelVisitor.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.sampleapp.codegen.InputFileGenerator.visit(InputFileGenerator.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.sampleapp.command.GeneratePageCommand.execute(GeneratePageCommand.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.ui.widgets.test.wssample.GSTCGenerateCommand.generatePages(GSTCGenerateCommand.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.ui.widgets.test.wssample.GSTCGenerateCommand.execute(GSTCGenerateCommand.java:71)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.ui.widgets.test.ClientTestDelegateCommand.commandFactoryExecution(ClientTestDelegateCommand.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.ui.widgets.test.ClientTestDelegateCommand.execute(ClientTestDelegateCommand.java:99)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:419)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:359)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:254)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:294)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:466)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:374)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1059)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:264)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:91)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.performFinish(WizardPageManager.java:262)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.DynamicWizard.performFinish(DynamicWizard.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:853)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:438)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:269)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:290)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:343)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:159)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

The WSDL is for a web service that I will have to access through my own endpoints. I was just trying to create a test client to start building my endpoints on top of it. Will these warnings cause me any trouble to access to this web service?

Answer (score 0):

Change Settings of your Eclipse :

```
To generate the Web service client without errors, you must make the following settings.
 1.  Choose Window → Preferences → Web Services.
 2.  Under Axis Emitter specify: Wsdl2Java. 
 3.  Select Prefers Building Beans to Straight Arrays for Wrapped XML Array Types.
If you leave this step out, then two-dimensional arrays are created during    generation for the GenericPropertyTable type.
```